# Download Progress with MediaElement WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I use MediaElement to play a Stream music and get dowloaded percent of that file by DownloadProgress, but it's alway 0 or 1. how to get actualy dowloaded percent of that file.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to manually increase the value of Progress bar according the condition, here is the code sample

```
//Create a Delegate that matches 
//the Signature of the ProgressBar's SetValue method
private delegate void UpdateProgressBarDelegate(
        System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, Object value);


private void Process()
{
    //Configure the ProgressBar
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = short.MaxValue;
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0;

    //Stores the value of the ProgressBar
    double value = 0;

    //Create a new instance of our ProgressBar Delegate that points
    // to the ProgressBar's SetValue method.
    UpdateProgressBarDelegate updatePbDelegate = 
        new UpdateProgressBarDelegate(ProgressBar1.SetValue);

    //Tight Loop: Loop until the ProgressBar.Value reaches the max
    do
    {
        value += 1;

        /*Update the Value of the ProgressBar:
            1) Pass the "updatePbDelegate" delegate
               that points to the ProgressBar1.SetValue method
            2) Set the DispatcherPriority to "Background"
            3) Pass an Object() Array containing the property
               to update (ProgressBar.ValueProperty) and the new value */
        Dispatcher.Invoke(updatePbDelegate, 
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, 
            new object[] { ProgressBar.ValueProperty, value });
    }
    while (ProgressBar1.Value != ProgressBar1.Maximum);
}
```

and here is the complete [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38555/WPF-ProgressBar)

Answer (score 0):

DownloadProgress is a percentage value between 0 and 1. So you have to multiply it with 100.
[MSDN Documentation form DownloadProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.downloadprogress.aspx)

Comment: DownloadProgress is a percentage value between 0 and 1.But DownloadProgress not is downloaded progress of file, DownloadProgress is downloaded progress of packet even mediaElement get it.And I went get downloaded progress of file.